# converting google sheets to excel and also send email to multiple recipients - syntax error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Hi There I merged two of the ideologies/codes however my code keeps giving me a syntax error. I am sure that this almost correct but unable to identify the error

```
function myFunction() {

var message = "This is a test of HTML <br><br> Line two";

var recipientsTO = "shrikant.ravi@droom.in" + "," + "Bhavishya.saini@droom.in";
var recipientsCC = "Lipika.uniyal@droom.in";
var Subject = "Vacation Approval Request";
var html = message;

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const nameFile = ss.getName() + ".xlsx";
const requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer 
 "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};  
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mytzfrl159TLMjMupziSKOrRJadsPKSLxYtaAvZTWt0/edit#gid=0"+ 
  ss.getId() + "/export?format=xlsx";
 const result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  const contents = result.getContent();

 MailApp.sendEmail({to: recipientsTO,
cc: recipientsCC,
subject: Subject,
htmlBody: html,}; 
              {attachments:[{fileName:nameFile, content:contents, mimeType:"MICROSOFT_EXCEL"}]};     
})
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to say more about what isn't working. Do you see an error message? If so, what is it? It is not producing the expected output? If not, what output do you see and what output do you expect?

Comment: In your script, how about modifying `MailApp.sendEmail({to: recipientsTO,cc: recipientsCC,subject: Subject,htmlBody: html,}; {attachments:[{fileName:nameFile, content:contents, mimeType:"MICROSOFT_EXCEL"}]};})` to `MailApp.sendEmail({to: recipientsTO,cc: recipientsCC,subject: Subject,htmlBody: html,attachments: [{ fileName: nameFile, content: contents, mimeType: "MICROSOFT_EXCEL" }]});`?

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for your input this works totally fine now

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike looks like i ran in an issue with this .. seems like it sends the attachment well ..however upon downloading the file its gives an error that the file isn't supported...any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sendAttachment() {
    var message = "This is a test of HTML <br><br> Line two";

    var recipientsTO = "foo@bar.baz";
    var recipientsCC = "baz@bat.cat"; 
    var subject = "Vacation Approval Request";
    var html = message;

    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const nameFile = ss.getName() + ".xlsx";
    const requestData = {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
    };  
    const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?format=xlsx";
    const result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url ,requestData);  
    const contents = result.getBlob();

    MailApp.sendEmail(
        recipientsTO,
        subject,
        html,
        {
            cc: recipientsCC,
            name: nameFile,
            attachments: [contents]
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: @TheMaster I am not the one who posted this answer. although you are still welcome to assist with the issue as it is not resolved fully